# Equation alignment again: align combined with gather

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath

Consider the following code and the corresponding result

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
V1:
\begin{align*}
A_1e^{i\omega t}+A_2e^{-i\omega t}
&=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(e^{i(\omega t+\phi)}+e^{-i(\omega t+\phi)}\right)\\
&=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(e^{i\omega}\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right)
+e^{-i\omega}\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)\right)
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}A_1=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right)\\
A_2=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad
\begin{cases}C\cos\phi=A_1+A_2\\
iC\sin\phi=A_1-A_2\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

V2:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{align*}
A_1e^{i\omega t}+A_2e^{-i\omega t}
&=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(e^{i(\omega t+\phi)}+e^{-i(\omega t+\phi)}\right)\\
&=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(e^{i\omega}\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right)
+e^{-i\omega}\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)\right)
\end{align*}\\
\begin{cases}A_1=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right)\\
A_2=\tfrac{C}{2}\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad
\begin{cases}C\cos\phi=A_1+A_2\\
iC\sin\phi=A_1-A_2\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get the horizontal alignment of the first variant and the vertical alignment of the second?

Basically I need a compact succession of centered aligned groups of equations.

Important: Without modifying the standard alignment parameters. 
Worst case scenario: to eat the vertical space between the align environments (possible?).

*Note: The second variant gives an error but generates the PDF.*

Comment: Use `aligned`, not `align*`.

Comment: @Bernard thank you. this solved the issue. should I delete the Q?

Comment: Not sure – it might be helpful to beginners to better understand the differences  between the basic ammath environments and their variants(aligned, gathered, alignedat), which are explained in  `§3.7, Alignment building blocks`, of the documentation (`amsldoc.pdf`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `align` can be used inside of `gather`, the alignment is not always optimal. There is another problem, though: `cases` adds quite a large horizontal space at the right, if the second column is not used.

I suggest a different environment for systems and to use `aligned`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{sys}
 {%
  \left\{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% like cases
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}%
 }
 {%
  \end{array}%
  \right.
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
A_1e^{i\omega t}+A_2e^{-i\omega t}
  &= \tfrac{C}{2}(e^{i(\omega t+\phi)}+e^{-i(\omega t+\phi)})\\
  &=\tfrac{C}{2}(e^{i\omega}(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)
    +e^{-i\omega}(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi))
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{sys}
  A_1=\tfrac{C}{2}(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi) \\
  A_2=\tfrac{C}{2}(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi)
\end{sys}
\qquad\to\qquad
\begin{sys}
  C\cos\phi=A_1+A_2  \\
  iC\sin\phi=A_1-A_2
\end{sys}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
A_1e^{i\omega t}+A_2e^{-i\omega t}
  &=\tfrac{C}{2}(e^{i(\omega t+\phi)}+e^{-i(\omega t+\phi)})\\
  &=\tfrac{C}{2}(e^{i\omega}(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)
    +e^{-i\omega}(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi))
\end{aligned}\\
\begin{cases}
  A_1=\tfrac{C}{2}(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi) \\
  A_2=\tfrac{C}{2}(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi)
\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad
\begin{cases}
  C\cos\phi=A_1+A_2 \\
  iC\sin\phi=A_1-A_2
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I added the version with `cases` to show the difference.

[image]